# Cypress,io setUpNodeEvents: cy.task is missing function properties from returned object

Tags: cypress

I have a node function that returns an object literal. That object will have various properties, among them a function property. When I set up a task via cypress setUpNodeEvents to call this function and use that in a cypress test, the returned object no longer has the function property; it is now undefined.

Can anyone see why the function property is lost?

**node function**

```
module.exports = build = () => {
 return {
  myFunc() {}
 };
}
```

**cypress.config**

```
const build = require('./builder');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  env,
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        buildObject: () => build(); 
      })
    },
  },
})
```

**cypress test file**

```
describe('transform', () => {
    it('should return object with a function property', () => {
        cy.task('buildObject')  
        .then(result => assert.isFunction(result.myFunc)); 
    });
});
```

I expect result,myFunc to be defined and be a Function but the result is 'expected undefined to be a function'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to this [Cypress task - arguments](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Arguments)

> **arg (Object)**
>
> An argument to send along with the event. This can be any value that can be serialized by JSON.stringify(). ***Unserializable*** types such as **functions**, regular expressions, or symbols **will be omitted** to null.

That refers to the input arguments, but the same rule applies to output results.

It's because the `task` boundary is an inter-process boundary and you cannot make calls across it. Same applies to the `cy.origin()` sandbox boundary.

To resolve the problem, call the function inside the task and return it's result.

There is logically no reason (as far as I can see) to pass back the function itself, as `cy.task('buildObject')` is a straight-forward wrapper for it.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I was thinking about this all wrong, as in what I was trying to achieve.